# The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration, when using flask with apache2

Tags: python, apache, flask

I'm new in python especially web application when tried to deploy flask framework on apache2 server, failed to show the code result on the html and got that error in error.log file:

```
[Mon Jul 31 22:02:43.415591 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 1422:tid 140548157462080] [client ::1:60120] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask', referer: http://localhost/
```

Although flask is installed and found that:

```
[Mon Jul 31 19:36:03.694144 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 226:tid 140149420746624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Although I was using pyton 3.11 not 3.10 and before install apache2 , what can I do ?